# Installing postgresql12-devel after postgres12 DB has already been created

Tags: postgresql, redhat

I have already installed and loaded a postgres12 instance on Redhat7.    Now we need the devel libs to compile additional packages like pg-hash64.

Has anyone installed other packages after postgres instance was already created?  Is there any impact to the binaries already installed?

Thanks for any info.

Comment: what is this exactly and how to install though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using the same source repository there should be no issue.

I have installed several PostgreSQL package on Centos 7 without any issue from :

```
repo id                  repo name                                        status
!pgdg12/7/x86_64         PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64         294
repolist: 294
```

Answer (score 1):

pifor was right, not an issue, Im a new user so its not letting me click the up arrow.

For postgres12.2 instance on Redhat7 to get pg-hash64 installed:

yum install postgresql12-devel-12.2-2PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 or version to match your postgres install

yum install llvm-toolset-7

in /usr/lib64:
 mkdir llvm5.0

in /usr/lib64/llvm5.0

ln -s /opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7/root/usr/bin bin

back in dir with unzipped package
make
make install
in psql:
CREATE EXTENSION hash64;